# Xcode (developer tools) for Mac 10.6.7

Tags: xcode, macos, gdb

Where can I get Xcode for my older computer? I need to have gdb installed because I'm supposed to use it in a class I'm taking. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Xcode 3.2.6](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg). You may have to log in before pasting the link into your browser.

Answer (score 2):

[Xcode 4.2](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_for_snow_leopard/xcode_4.2_for_snow_leopard.dmg) will run on 10.6 Snow Leopard. You have to download it from Apple's Developer website, as the version on the Mac App Store (4.3.2) now is Lion only. You may need to update to 10.6.8 as well, which you can do by running Software Update.